# Environment not properly prepared when installing NextCloud for the first time

Tags: php, kubernetes, config, nextcloud

I'm trying to deploy Nextcloud using Helm. First I tried it on my local machine (MacOS Big Sur) using Minikube (Kubernetes 1.21) and it was up and running in 5 minutes.. Unfortunately it will not succeed at work. I'm using there CentOS7 to eventually deploy Nextcloud on a Kubernetes cluster 1.21.

The error I retrieve: `Environment not properly prepared in /var/www/html/lib/private/Console/Application.php:162`. See image below:
[image: Screenshot 2022-04-01 at 13 32 08]

My values.yml file looks like this:

```yaml
## Official nextcloud image version
## ref: https://hub.docker.com/r/library/nextcloud/tags/
##
image:
  repository: nextcloud
  tag: 23.0.2-apache
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  # pullSecrets:
  #   - myRegistrKeySecretName

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""
podAnnotations: {}
deploymentAnnotations: {}

# Number of replicas to be deployed
replicaCount: 1

secuurityContext:
  runAsUser: 33
  runAsGroup: 33
  runAsNonRoot: true

## Allowing use of ingress controllers
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/
##
ingress:
  enabled: false
  # className: nginx
  annotations: {}
  #  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-body-size: 4G
  #  kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  #  cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod
  #  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |-
  #    server_tokens off;
  #    proxy_hide_header X-Powered-By;

  #    rewrite ^/.well-known/webfinger /public.php?service=webfinger last;
  #    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta /public.php?service=host-meta last;
  #    rewrite ^/.well-known/host-meta.json /public.php?service=host-meta-json;
  #    location = /.well-known/carddav {
  #      return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
  #    }
  #    location = /.well-known/caldav {
  #      return 301 $scheme://$host/remote.php/dav;
  #    }
  #    location = /robots.txt {
  #      allow all;
  #      log_not_found off;
  #      access_log off;
  #    }
  #    location ~ ^/(?:build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
  #      deny all;
  #    }
  #    location ~ ^/(?:autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
  #      deny all;
  #    }
  # tls:
  #   - secretName: nextcloud-tls
  #     hosts:
  #       - nextcloud.kube.home
  labels: {}
  path: /
  pathType: Prefix


# Allow configuration of lifecycle hooks
# ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/attach-handler-lifecycle-event/
lifecycle: {}
  # postStartCommand: []
  # preStopCommand: []

phpClientHttpsFix:
  enabled: false
  protocol: https

nextcloud:
  host: nextcloud.kube.home
  username: admin
  password: changeme
  ## Use an existing secret
  existingSecret:
    enabled: false
    # secretName: nameofsecret
    # usernameKey: username
    # passwordKey: password
    # tokenKey: serverinfo_token
    # smtpUsernameKey: smtp_username
    # smtpPasswordKey: smtp_password
  update: 0
  # If web server is not binding default port, you can define it
  # containerPort: 8080
  datadir: /var/www/html/data
  persistence:
    subPath:
  mail:
    enabled: false
    fromAddress: user
    domain: domain.com
    smtp:
      host: domain.com
      secure: ssl
      port: 465
      authtype: LOGIN
      name: user
      password: pass
  # PHP Configuration files
  # Will be injected in /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d for apache image and in /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d when nginx.enabled: true
  phpConfigs: {}
  # Default config files
  # IMPORTANT: Will be used only if you put extra configs, otherwise default will come from nextcloud itself
  # Default confgurations can be found here: https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/16.0/apache/config
  defaultConfigs:
    # To protect /var/www/html/config
    .htaccess: true
    # Redis default configuration
    redis.config.php: true
    # Apache configuration for rewrite urls
    apache-pretty-urls.config.php: true
    # Define APCu as local cache
    apcu.config.php: true
    # Apps directory configs
    apps.config.php: true
    # Used for auto configure database
    autoconfig.php: true
    # SMTP default configuration
    smtp.config.php: true
  # Extra config files created in /var/www/html/config/
  # ref: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/15/admin_manual/configuration_server/config_sample_php_parameters.html#multiple-config-php-file
  configs: {}

  # For example, to use S3 as primary storage
  # ref: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13/admin_manual/configuration_files/primary_storage.html#simple-storage-service-s3
  #
  #  configs:
  #    s3.config.php: |-
  #      <?php
  #      $CONFIG = array (
  #        'objectstore' => array(
  #          'class' => '\\OC\\Files\\ObjectStore\\S3',
  #          'arguments' => array(
  #            'bucket'     => 'my-bucket',
  #            'autocreate' => true,
  #            'key'        => 'xxx',
  #            'secret'     => 'xxx',
  #            'region'     => 'us-east-1',
  #            'use_ssl'    => true
  #          )
  #        )
  #      );

  ## Strategy used to replace old pods
  ## IMPORTANT: use with care, it is suggested to leave as that for upgrade purposes
  ## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#strategy
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
    # type: RollingUpdate
    # rollingUpdate:
    #   maxSurge: 1
    #   maxUnavailable: 0

  ##
  ## Extra environment variables
  extraEnv:
  #  - name: SOME_SECRET_ENV
  #    valueFrom:
  #      secretKeyRef:
  #        name: nextcloud
  #        key: secret_key

  # Extra mounts for the pods. Example shown is for connecting a legacy NFS volume
  # to NextCloud pods in Kubernetes. This can then be configured in External Storage
  extraVolumes:
  #  - name: nfs
  #    nfs:
  #      server: "10.0.0.1"
  #      path: "/nextcloud_data"
  #      readOnly: false
  extraVolumeMounts:
  #  - name: nfs
  #    mountPath: "/legacy_data"

  # Extra secuurityContext parameters. For example you may need to define runAsNonRoot directive
  # extraSecurityContext:
  #   runAsUser: "33"
  #   runAsGroup: "33"
  #   runAsNonRoot: true
  #   readOnlyRootFilesystem: true

nginx:
  ## You need to set an fpm version of the image for nextcloud if you want to use nginx!
  enabled: false
  image:
    repository: nginx
    tag: alpine
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  config:
    # This generates the default nginx config as per the nextcloud documentation
    default: true
    # custom: |-
    #     worker_processes  1;..

  resources: {}

internalDatabase:
  enabled: true
  name: nextcloud

##
## External database configuration
##
externalDatabase:
  enabled: false

  ## Supported database engines: mysql or postgresql
  type: mysql

  ## Database host
  host:

  ## Database user
  user: nextcloud

  ## Database password
  password:

  ## Database name
  database: nextcloud

  ## Use a existing secret
  existingSecret:
    enabled: false
    # secretName: nameofsecret
    # usernameKey: username
    # passwordKey: password

##
## MariaDB chart configuration
##
mariadb:
  ## Whether to deploy a mariadb server to satisfy the applications database requirements. To use an external database set this to false and configure the externalDatabase parameters
  enabled: false

  auth:
    database: nextcloud
    username: nextcloud
    password: changeme

  architecture: standalone

  ## Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
  ##
  primary:
    persistence:
      enabled: false
      # storageClass: ""
      accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
      size: 8Gi

##
## PostgreSQL chart configuration
## for more options see https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/postgresql
##
postgresql:
  enabled: false
  postgresqlUsername: nextcloud
  postgresqlPassword: changeme
  postgresqlDatabase: nextcloud
  persistence:
    enabled: false
    # storageClass: ""

##
## Redis chart configuration
## for more options see https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis
##

redis:
  enabled: false
  auth:
    enabled: true
    password: 'changeme'

## Cronjob to execute Nextcloud background tasks
## ref: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/latest/admin_manual/configuration_server/background_jobs_configuration.html#webcron
##
cronjob:
  enabled: false
  # Nexcloud image is used as default but only curl is needed
  image: {}
    # repository: nextcloud
    # tag: 16.0.3-apache
    # pullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    # pullSecrets:
    #   - myRegistrKeySecretName
  # Every 5 minutes
  # Note: Setting this to any any other value than 5 minutes might
  #  cause issues with how nextcloud background jobs are executed
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  annotations: {}
  # Set curl's insecure option if you use e.g. self-signed certificates
  curlInsecure: false
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 5
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 2
  # If not set, nextcloud deployment one will be set
  # resources:
    # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
    # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
    # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
    # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
    # limits:
    #  cpu: 100m
    #  memory: 128Mi
    # requests:
    #  cpu: 100m
    #  memory: 128Mi

  # If not set, nextcloud deployment one will be set
  # nodeSelector: {}

  # If not set, nextcloud deployment one will be set
  # tolerations: []

  # If not set, nextcloud deployment one will be set
  # affinity: {}

service:
  type: ClusterIP
  port: 8080
  loadBalancerIP: nil
  nodePort: nil

## Enable persistence using Persistent Volume Claims
## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/
##
persistence:
  # Nextcloud Data (/var/www/html)
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
  ## nextcloud data Persistent Volume Storage Class
  ## If defined, storageClassName: <storageClass>
  ## If set to "-", storageClassName: "", which disables dynamic provisioning
  ## If undefined (the default) or set to null, no storageClassName spec is
  ##   set, choosing the default provisioner.  (gp2 on AWS, standard on
  ##   GKE, AWS & OpenStack)
  ##
  # storageClass: "-"

  ## A manually managed Persistent Volume and Claim
  ## Requires persistence.enabled: true
  ## If defined, PVC must be created manually before volume will be bound
  # existingClaim:

  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  size: 8Gi

  ## Use an additional pvc for the data directory rather than a subpath of the default PVC
  ## Useful to store data on a different storageClass (e.g. on slower disks)
  nextcloudData:
    enabled: false
    subPath:
    annotations: {}
    # storageClass: "-"
    # existingClaim:
    accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
    size: 8Gi

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi

## Liveness and readiness probe values
## Ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-probes
##
livenessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 3
  successThreshold: 1
readinessProbe:
  enabled: true
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 3
  successThreshold: 1
startupProbe:
  enabled: false
  initialDelaySeconds: 30
  periodSeconds: 10
  timeoutSeconds: 5
  failureThreshold: 30
  successThreshold: 1


## Enable pod autoscaling using HorizontalPodAutoscaler
## ref: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/
##
hpa:
  enabled: false
  cputhreshold: 60
  minPods: 1
  maxPods: 10

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}


## Prometheus Exporter / Metrics
##
metrics:
  enabled: false

  replicaCount: 1
  # The metrics exporter needs to know how you serve Nextcloud either http or https
  https: false
  # Use API token if set, otherwise fall back to password authentication
  # https://github.com/xperimental/nextcloud-exporter#token-authentication
  # Currently you still need to set the token manually in your nextcloud install
  token: ""
  timeout: 5s

  image:
    repository: xperimental/nextcloud-exporter
    tag: 0.5.0
    pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

  ## Metrics exporter resource requests and limits
  ## ref: http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/compute-resources/
  ##
  # resources: {}

  ## Metrics exporter pod Annotation and Labels
  # podAnnotations: {}

  # podLabels: {}

  service:
    type: ClusterIP
    ## Use serviceLoadBalancerIP to request a specific static IP,
    ## otherwise leave blank
    # loadBalancerIP:
    annotations:
      prometheus.io/scrape: "true"
      prometheus.io/port: "9205"
    labels: {}

rbac:
  enabled: false
  serviceaccount:
    create: true
    name: nextcloud-serviceaccount
```

Has this something to do with some config.php files I need to add?